# Autolayout UIScrollView with a content view and UIImageView not sizing properly

Tags: swift, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout, uiimageview

I'm having some problems with the `UIView` where all content is added as subviews `(ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW)`. I've added some borders so you can see where it's going wrong.

I'm adding all my views as subviews to my content view because they need to overlap and can zoom togethor. The content view is not stretched in width/height as the `UIImageView` and my custom subclass of `UIView` for drawing. What is weird because everything is inside of the content view.

Because of this my touchHandler is only being recognized in the smaller not streched view aka `"ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW"` and not further. This should be stretched like all the rest to work proper. Still I can draw further then the border of the content view if i start in the content view.

Thanks in advance!

```
var afbeelding = UIImage()
var drawView = DrawingCanvas()
var imageView = UIImageView()

@IBOutlet var ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW: UIView!

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var EraserButtonOutlet: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self
    
    imageView = UIImageView(image: afbeelding) //Setting image of user as background
    
    scrollView.contentSize = afbeelding.size //Setting size of image as contentsize for scrollview
    
    scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2 // 2 finger panning and zooming. 1 is for drawing
    scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2
    
    drawView.frame = imageView.frame // Everything should have the same frame size etc
    ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW.frame = imageView.frame

    drawView.isOpaque = false // false otherwise it's not transparant as top view
    
    ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW.addSubview(imageView) // Adding all in the same view for zooming at the same time
    ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW.addSubview(drawView)
    
    scrollView.addSubview(ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW) // Adding the contentview to the scrollview

    drawView.dag = dag // Setting object in custom view for handeling the lines
    
    /*Testing
     ImageView for background image
     DrawView where user can draw on the background image (Custom class for storing everything)
     ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW for putting the 2 as subview so the zoom would be the same
     */
    
    ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW.layer.borderWidth = 10
    
    scrollView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    
    drawView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    drawView.layer.borderWidth = 15
    
    imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 20
    
    setZoomScale()
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW
}

func setZoomScale() {
    var minZoom = min(self.view.bounds.size.width / ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height / ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW.bounds.size.height);

    if (minZoom > 1.0) {
        minZoom = 1.0;
    }

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minZoom;
    scrollView.zoomScale = minZoom;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 8.0
}
```

Constraints:

[image: Example]
[image: Storyboard]
[image: Constraints]
[image: Constraints2]

Comment: Very difficult to offer help with the info you've given. Best is to create a [mre] so we can run your current code and see what's happening.

Comment: Just to test in case you did not before, try to set the frames after making calling addSubview function. Just to check if everything is fine. Also, try to set hardcoded dimension to see if they are set properly in order to debug your views.

Comment: I think the biggest problem is that you are mixing the use of Storyboard/AutoLayout, which automatically creates subview/superview relationships and dynamically computes frames, alongside programmatically creating views, assigning subviews, and statically assigning frame sizes. These are probably overwriting each other somehow. I can reproduce the behavior you are seeing, and I'll post an actual answer if I figure it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following changes in your code, and it appears that the `ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW` now has the correct frame:

1. Declare your `imageView` variable this way: (instead of `var imageView = UIImageView()`)

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
```

Then add a UIImageView in the Storyboard as a subview of `ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW`. Make sure you also add constraints to make this view the same size as `ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW`.

2. remove these lines: (let the storyboard handle this)

```
ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW.addSubview(imageView)
...
scrollView.addSubview(ALLES_SAMEN_VIEW)
```

3. replace this line:

```
imageView = UIImageView(image: afbeelding)
```

with this:

```
imageView.image = afbeelding
```

NOTES:

- if you want to programmatically add the subviews (as you originally did), you also need to programmatically add constraints to make the frames match. But since you are already using the storyboard, you might as well let it handle these relationships
- these changes don't make the `drawView` correctly sized: you will probably also want to instantiate the `drawView` using the storyboard and add constraints, the same way I did with `imageView`
- as I have it, the pinch zoom gesture probably isn't doing what you want, but that's outside the scope of your question, I think

Comment: Hey thanks man, I've figured that I was wrong with declaring the imageView like you said, and for the constrains I've added an equal with and height for the drawing view and image view. This seems to work! I've accepted your answer.